# SendKeys send more keys than expected

Tags: java, selenium, ui-automation, android-testing, selendroid

I'm trying to test a mobile application on android, I am trying to login but when I execute the sendkeys of the password, what happens is that the password is sent but for some reason writes an extra letter in the password (the letter is y), does anyone know what it can be? In username it writes everything right.
thanks

```
MobileElement el2 = (MobileElement) driver.findElementById("password");
el2.sendKeys("DPY16085");
```

Comment: Where is the extra **y** written? at the front or at the back or in the mid of **DPY16085**?

Comment: front, it´s send DPY16085y

Comment: How do you know it's DPY16085y if it's password block. And another question is does application tested for manually entry of password. It might happen application may have some issue

Comment: You can try one thing you can pass ENTER key with your password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While entering the data in input field if your device or emulator keypad is open then this problem occurs the solution is you have to dismiss the keypad if you are entering the data using sendkeys 
you need to set this capabilities in DesiredCapabilities:

```
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();    
dc.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
dc.setCapability("resetKeyboard", true);
```